# Scaling x-axis values containing dates - dates not showing (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to scale the x-axis of my bar graph, which contains dates. I have used the `set_major_locator()` function of matplotlib for the same. Here is my code:

```py
def plot_var(country):
    """
    Plots a bar chart of the given variable over the date range
    """
    
    y = confirmed_data[confirmed_data['Country_Region']==country]["TargetValue"]
    x = confirmed_data[confirmed_data['Country_Region']==country]['Date']
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=30))
    plt.title("Plot of \"ConfirmedCases\"",fontsize=18)
    plt.bar(x=x,height=y,color='blue')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=14,rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
    plt.show()
```

However, my graph does not show any values in the x-axis. I don't understand why this is happening. Hope you can help me with this!

P.S. I have included the necessary libraries (matplotlib.pyplot and matplotlib.dates) for the same.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goze4.png)

Comment: I created test data in my environment and ran the code, and it correctly displays the date and time correctly.

Comment: Wild guess would be that your dates are still strings, not dates.